# What's the coordinate ability?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm on chapter 57 on *Attack on Titan*, and a "coordinate ability" keeps getting mentioned -- here by Hanji, but also earlier by either Bertholdt or Reiner (who apparently didn't want it to fall into the wrong hands). But what exactly is this coordinate ability?

I skipped a lot of the chapters up to 34 because they were just rehashings of the stuff in the anime, and I skimmed over a lot of the Survey Corps action in the woods, since it was getting too repetitious for me, so it's possible I might just have missed something.

**Edit (taken from my comment in the answers):** As an explanation to other readers, I was confused about this since at least in English, "coordinate" is pretty ambiguous without any further qualification. (It could be something geographical.) From the way Reiner and Bertholdt were talking about it, it sounded a bit like it could simply be a piece of crucial information that Eren might have in his lost memory.

[image: Reiner and Berthodt's conversation.]

Moreover, because of how Hanji was describing it merely as a "coordinate ability", it still wasn't clear to me.

Comment: It's the power to control other titans, when Eren was kidnapped he saw the titan that eat his mother and then he called another titan: [specific page](http://www.mangareader.net/shingeki-no-kyojin/50/350)
It might be also something more than that, but I don't want to post spoilers since you are not on the latest manga!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Titans can have different types of abilities, like shifting back to human form (aka [Titan Shifters](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Titan_Shifter)), or putting armor on themselves (eg: [Armored Titan](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Reiner_Braun), [Annie](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Reiner_Braun) hiding the back of her neck, ...). The third ability that was shown, was that of the Coordinate.

The Coordinate ability is basically the ability to control Titans. If the ability is controlled properly it can command all Titans to do whatever you want them to do.

> This is how humans were able to built the walls as sturdy and as big as they are right now.

As far as the story goes, it does not seem to work on Titan Shifters and there is supposed to be only one Titan with the Coordinate ability.

> Although the [Beast Titan](http://shingekinokyojin.wikia.com/wiki/Beast_Titan) was shown to have a similar ability.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense, although "coordinate" just sounds terribly ambiguous, at least when I'm not completely paying attention. (I mean, I wasn't sure if it were just some geographical coordinate, and with Eren's lost memory and all, I was wondering if he simply had something in his memory that might be described as a coordinate)... :P I do get why a one-word description of the ability is nice to have though.

Comment: yes "command" would be a better name :D

Comment: @Maroon maybe it is Engrish and makes sense in Japanese?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: yeah, that struck me as pretty probable: ambiguities from double-meanings generally don't really translate across languages. (It's also possible the translation I was reading was just bad, but somehow, given how many results I got for `snk coordinate ability`, that seems doubtful.)

Answer (score 0):

the coordinate is the ability to control other titans (abnormals) but Eren never had that power. He only got it when touching the mother of Zeke, his father's first wife(the smiling titan) who was of the royal family.

Comment: Please elaborate and provide sources/references.

Comment: The coordinate is the ability to control other titans (abnormals). And Eren can only activate his by touching someone with royal blood like the smiling titan. https://www.mangareader.net/shingeki-no-kyojin/115/11

if you read the chapter below, after Eren and Zeke concluded on how to save Eldia, Zeke refused to touch Eren but instead gave him a ball.
https://www.mangareader.net/shingeki-no-kyojin/115/19

However, Eren activated the Coordinate but two time.

Comment: If you watched the third season you realise that Eren failed to stop Lord Reis because He did not have contact with someone of royal blood. If he had direct contact with Historia while telling Lord Reis to stop, He would have stopped immediatly. To sum it all Royal blood + Founding Titan gives the Host all the abilities of the founding titan. 


that is how the wall was built. But there is so much left unanswered....

Comment: As a manga reader, I already know the facts you laid out. However, this is a Q&A site so your references should be included in your answer itself, not as a comment. To add, scanlated sources and sources from illegal/fan translations are not allowed or are heavily discouraged as this site does not and will never support piracy.

Comment: Kk sorry for that, I am new here, didnt know the rules and just wanted to contribute by answering to the initial post. So what exactly do you want to know? or what dont you know?

Did you know that the second time Eren used the coordinate, He had no contact with royal blood but an ackerman?(Mikasa)

Which was weird in a way.

Comment: As long as you answer the OP's question, there is no limit to how much you can include in the answer, as long as it is relevant. Preferably, answers should be discussed. Just remember to include sources/references. And regarding the second time he used coordinate, when was that? I could not recall the chapter. Only remember him using it while in contact with Dina Fritz.

Comment: He used it the second time when he was running away with Mikasa on his back. That should never have happened but it did. He redirected the Titans from The smiling Titan to the armored titan.